# Converting CS_UID to write it to UART

Tags: c, hex, ascii, microcontroller, uart

this is my first time posting, so please be patient with 
me.. I need help with my Code.. i am very unexperienced. I want to write 
the CS_UID (the unique ID of my microcontroller) to UART, using this 
function:

```
void appWriteDataToUart(uint8_t* aData, uint8_t aLength);
```

Therefore I think I need to convert the hexadecimal `CS_UID` (64bit long) 
which is defined as follows for example:

```
#define CS_UID 0x1234567890abcdff
```

into something that makes sense and is possible to be written to UART.

Someone told me this would help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int hex_to_int(char c) {
    int first = c / 16 - 3;
    int second = c % 16;
    int result = first*10 + second;
    if(result > 9) result--;
    return result;
}

int hex_to_ascii(char c, char d) {
    int high = hex_to_int(c) * 16;
    int low = hex_to_int(d);
    return high+low;
}

int main() {
    const char* st = "48656C6C6F3B";
    int length = strlen(st);
    int i;
    char buf = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(i % 2 != 0){
                    printf("%c", hex_to_ascii(buf, st[i]));
            }else{
                    buf = st[i];
            }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to use that. I'm clueless. These functions return 
`int` and use `printf` and %c.

I tried it like this but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CS_UID 0x1234567890abcdff

int hex_to_int(char c) {
int first = c / 16 - 3;
int second = c % 16;
int result = first*10 + second;
if(result > 9) result--;
return result;
}

int hex_to_ascii(char c, char d) {
int high = hex_to_int(c) * 16;
int low = hex_to_int(d);
return high+low;
}

int main (void) {

    char st[16] = CS_UID;
    char csuid_array[8]; //this is the array i want to write to UART later? right or wrong?
    int length = strlen(st);
    int j;
    char buf = 0;
for (j=0; j < length; j++){
    if(j % 2 != 0){
        csuid_array[j] = hex_to_ascii(buf,st[j]);
    }
    else{
        buf = st[j];
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

i'd appreciate any help or other solution! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a C library?  If you can use `printf`, you don't really need all this extra stuff.

Comment: yes but i want to have the hexadezimal value convertet to a human readable string and send it via appWriteDataToUart() so printf wont help, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you want to send the ASCII representation of the value so that it is human readable on a terminal program.  `printf()` (and `sprintf()`) can do the conversion for you, so you don't need those other "hex" routines.

```
#define CS_UID 0x1234567890abcdffU

uint8_t csuid_array[19];  // extra bytes for "0x" and NULL terminator
sprintf((char*)csuid_array, "0x%016llX", CSUID); // that's two letter 'l' between '%016' and 'X'
appWriteDataToUart(csuid_array, 18); // extra bytes for "0x"
```

Comment: yes you got that right, sorry for my bad explanation. i tried what you have suggested, i got this warning: "format '%016lX' expects type 'long unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'long long int'" and this as output: 03!(!#;8!# with "#define CS_UID 0x1234567890abcdff"

Comment: Try changing the format specifier from `0x$016lx` to `0x$016llx` (two letter 'l').  Go read about [printf format specifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) to understand that string and why two 'l' might help.  I'll update the code in my original answer.

Comment: Those `$`s in your comment were meant to be `%`s, weren't they?

Comment: @alk yes, my comment has a typo.  Thanks.

Comment: okay thank you, i tried it still didnt work for me, but i found another solution so simple its unbelievable.
You define these:

#define to_string2(x)   #x
#define to_string(x)    to_string2( x )

and then just call the function to write to uart like this:

appWriteDataToUart(to_string(CS_UID), sizeof(to_string(CS_UID)));